# React plugin to write files to server in development mode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I am looking for a ready solution for the React development mode that allows modifying server-side files from the client-side scripts.

How it can work? For example, it is a small server script or an extension for create-react-app that can receive upload requests from the client-side script to modify source files.

I need to renew several source files (files2) automatically when other source files (files1) are modified. The client-side react script will process the js object taken from the custom webpack loader, that loads source files1, then I need to renew some source files2 that is using by another webpack loader.

This scheme will not be active in a production mode.

I know I can write my own nodejs based server that will communicate with my client script and modify files, but I am looking for existing solutions and furthermore, I'd like to use the same connection that React development server created to avoid CORS headaches, etc.

Do you know something good about this?